# how can I insert a background image in react for the whole screen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I am developing a react web page.

```
 var sectionStyle = {
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%",
      backgroundImage: "url(" +  background  + ")"
    };

<div style={ sectionStyle }></div>
```

This way, I tried to insert a background image. The background image is visualized only up to the amount of content available inside the div. 
I want to view it on the whole screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This way:

```
 var sectionStyle = {
      width: 100vh,
      height: 100vh,
      backgroundImage: "url(" +  background  + ")"
    };

<div style={ sectionStyle }></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `height: "100vh"` instead of 100%

Comment: Now this uses viewport-units. Those are not always supported especially in older versions of android and internet explorer. So use with caution depending on your project scope.